# error 111 nginx with nuxtapp and plesk server

Tags: nginx, docker-compose, nuxt.js

I created a nuxt application that I decided to put in dockers to be able to host on a plesk server, but I encounter an error, when I put the domain name in the browser I see a 502 error and when I consult the docker of the nginx server I see a 111 error, I have done everything but nothing I still have this error.

- here is my docker-compose file :

```
version: '3.4'
services:
  busol_nuxt:
    container_name: busol_nuxt
    image: busol_nuxt
    ports:
      - "4000:4000"
    environment:
      NODE_ENV: production
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - ./nuxt/dist:/usr/src/app/dist
    networks:
      - busol_network

  busol_nginx:
    image: nginx:latest
    container_name: nginx_front_nuxt
    volumes:
      - ./nginx/conf.d/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
      - web-root:/var/www/blowstack
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    networks:
      - busol_network
    depends_on:
      - busol_nuxt
    restart: unless-stopped

networks:
  busol_network:
    driver: bridge

volumes:
  web-root:
```

- here is my default.conf file:

```
upstream docker {
   server busol_nuxt:4000;
 }
map $sent_http_content_type $expires {
   "text/html"                 epoch;
   "text/html; charset=utf-8"  epoch;
   default                     off;
}
server {
   listen          8080;             # the port nginx is listening on
   server_name     app.ariap.io;    # setup your domain here

   gzip            on;
   gzip_types      text/plain application/xml text/css application/javascript;
   gzip_min_length 1000;
   keepalive_timeout 650s;

   location / {
      expires $expires;

      proxy_ssl_verify off;  # désactive la vérification SSL
      proxy_redirect                      off;
      proxy_set_header Host               $host;
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP          $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For    $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto  $scheme;
      proxy_connect_timeout       1m;
      proxy_pass                          http://docker; 
      proxy_read_timeout 600s;
      fastcgi_buffers 8 500k;
      fastcgi_buffer_size 500k;
      fastcgi_connect_timeout 500s;
      fastcgi_send_timeout 500s;
      fastcgi_read_timeout 500s;
   }
}
```

- here is my docker file which contains my environment:

```
FROM node:lts-alpine
ENV NODE_ENV=production
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY ["package.json", "package-lock.json*", "npm-shrinkwrap.json*", "./"]
RUN npm install --production --silent && mv node_modules ../
COPY . .
EXPOSE 4000
RUN chown -R node /usr/src/app
USER node
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

- Here is what my file looks like:
  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4kjKN.png)
- when I try to access my application from a browser:
  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9t6mh.png)
- the container logs on the server:
  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g4hP3.png)

I checked my config several times but I didn't find anything so I checked the firewalls on the server, if the dockers were on the same network, if the dockers were working well and everything seemed fine.

Answer (score 0):

here is my dockerfile just in case :

```html
FROM alpine:3.15

ENV NODE_VERSION 14.19.1

RUN addgroup -g 1000 node \
    && adduser -u 1000 -G node -s /bin/sh -D node \
    && apk add --no-cache \
        libstdc++ \
    && apk add --no-cache --virtual .build-deps \
        curl \
    && ARCH= && alpineArch="$(apk --print-arch)" \
      && case "${alpineArch##*-}" in \
        x86_64) \
          ARCH='x64' \
          CHECKSUM="094790128069eccc9534214e7435c70bcafa221a0ef0f229c59418f8762704fa" \
          ;; \
        *) ;; \
      esac \
  && if [ -n "${CHECKSUM}" ]; then \
    set -eu; \
    curl -fsSLO --compressed "https://unofficial-builds.nodejs.org/download/release/v$NODE_VERSION/node-v$NODE_VERSION-linux-$ARCH-musl.tar.xz"; \
    echo "$CHECKSUM  node-v$NODE_VERSION-linux-$ARCH-musl.tar.xz" | sha256sum -c - \
      && tar -xJf "node-v$NODE_VERSION-linux-$ARCH-musl.tar.xz" -C /usr/local --strip-components=1 --no-same-owner \
      && ln -s /usr/local/bin/node /usr/local/bin/nodejs; \
  else \
    echo "Building from source" \
    # backup build
    && apk add --no-cache --virtual .build-deps-full \
        binutils-gold \
        g++ \
        gcc \
        gnupg \
        libgcc \
        linux-headers \
        make \
        python3 \
    # gpg keys listed at https://github.com/nodejs/node#release-keys
    && for key in \
      4ED778F539E3634C779C87C6D7062848A1AB005C \
      141F07595B7B3FFE74309A937405533BE57C7D57 \
      94AE36675C464D64BAFA68DD7434390BDBE9B9C5 \
      74F12602B6F1C4E913FAA37AD3A89613643B6201 \
      71DCFD284A79C3B38668286BC97EC7A07EDE3FC1 \
      8FCCA13FEF1D0C2E91008E09770F7A9A5AE15600 \
      C4F0DFFF4E8C1A8236409D08E73BC641CC11F4C8 \
      C82FA3AE1CBEDC6BE46B9360C43CEC45C17AB93C \
      DD8F2338BAE7501E3DD5AC78C273792F7D83545D \
      A48C2BEE680E841632CD4E44F07496B3EB3C1762 \
      108F52B48DB57BB0CC439B2997B01419BD92F80A \
      B9E2F5981AA6E0CD28160D9FF13993A75599653C \
    ; do \
      gpg --batch --keyserver hkps://keys.openpgp.org --recv-keys "$key" || \
      gpg --batch --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys "$key" ; \
    done \
    && curl -fsSLO --compressed "https://nodejs.org/dist/v$NODE_VERSION/node-v$NODE_VERSION.tar.xz" \
    && curl -fsSLO --compressed "https://nodejs.org/dist/v$NODE_VERSION/SHASUMS256.txt.asc" \
    && gpg --batch --decrypt --output SHASUMS256.txt SHASUMS256.txt.asc \
    && grep " node-v$NODE_VERSION.tar.xz\$" SHASUMS256.txt | sha256sum -c - \
    && tar -xf "node-v$NODE_VERSION.tar.xz" \
    && cd "node-v$NODE_VERSION" \
    && ./configure \
    && make -j$(getconf _NPROCESSORS_ONLN) V= \
    && make install \
    && apk del .build-deps-full \
    && cd .. \
    && rm -Rf "node-v$NODE_VERSION" \
    && rm "node-v$NODE_VERSION.tar.xz" SHASUMS256.txt.asc SHASUMS256.txt; \
  fi \
  && rm -f "node-v$NODE_VERSION-linux-$ARCH-musl.tar.xz" \
  && apk del .build-deps \
  # smoke tests
  && node --version \
  && npm --version

ENV YARN_VERSION 1.22.17

RUN apk add --no-cache --virtual .build-deps-yarn curl gnupg tar \
  && for key in \
    6A010C5166006599AA17F08146C2130DFD2497F5 \
  ; do \
    gpg --batch --keyserver hkps://keys.openpgp.org --recv-keys "$key" || \
    gpg --batch --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys "$key" ; \
  done \
  && curl -fsSLO --compressed "https://yarnpkg.com/downloads/$YARN_VERSION/yarn-v$YARN_VERSION.tar.gz" \
  && curl -fsSLO --compressed "https://yarnpkg.com/downloads/$YARN_VERSION/yarn-v$YARN_VERSION.tar.gz.asc" \
  && gpg --batch --verify yarn-v$YARN_VERSION.tar.gz.asc yarn-v$YARN_VERSION.tar.gz \
  && mkdir -p /opt \
  && tar -xzf yarn-v$YARN_VERSION.tar.gz -C /opt/ \
  && ln -s /opt/yarn-v$YARN_VERSION/bin/yarn /usr/local/bin/yarn \
  && ln -s /opt/yarn-v$YARN_VERSION/bin/yarnpkg /usr/local/bin/yarnpkg \
  && rm yarn-v$YARN_VERSION.tar.gz.asc yarn-v$YARN_VERSION.tar.gz \
  && apk del .build-deps-yarn \
  # smoke test
  && yarn --version



EXPOSE 4000


COPY ./busol /busol_nuxt_app
WORKDIR /busol_nuxt_app
COPY ./entrypoint.sh /busol_nuxt_app/

RUN npm set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/
RUN npm install -g npm@6.14.16
# Installer pm2
RUN npm install -g pm2
# RUN npm install -g npm@latest
RUN npm i
RUN npm run build

CMD [ "npm", "start"]
```

Comment: Hi, if this is update to your question, please add it there, here it will be lost. You can edit your question.